# Is it okay to call UIResponder.resignFirstResponder directly?

Tags: uikit, first-responder, resignfirstresponder

I just started to suspect that calling `resignFirstResponder` directly is not actually allowed. Unlike `NSResponder`, it's allowed to call `becomeFirstResponder` directly in UIKit. So far I was making assumption that calling `resignFirstResponder` would be okay too. But in fact, the manual says `resignFirstResponder` method is there to get notified, and mentions nothing about direct calling.

> Notifies this object that it has been asked to relinquish its status
>   as first responder in its window.

If it's designed in same way of how `NSResponder` works, direct calling to `resignFirstResponder` wouldn't be allowed though there's no obvious way to figure out validity of the call in the manual...

If it's been designed not to be called directly, directly calling to the method would be harmful or make code harder to maintain.

Is it okay to call `UIResponder.resignFirstResponder` method directly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be okay because [on another part of the manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), it says

> ...
>   To dismiss the keyboard, you call the `resignFirstResponder` method of
>   the text-based view that is currently the first responder. When a text
>   view resigns its first responder status, it ends its current editing
>   session, notifies its delegate of that fact, and dismisses the
>   keyboard. In other words, if you have a variable called `myTextField`
>   that points to the `UITextField` object that is currently the first
>   responder, dismissing the keyboard is as simple as doing the
>   following:
>
> ```
> [myTextField resignFirstResponder];
> ```
>
> Everything from that point on is handled for you automatically by the text object.